# a tag hover, active and visited don't work

Tags: css, hover

I put an a tag around some text and give it an id "mainpage". 
Then I add CCS for "mainpage", but somehow hover, active and visted effects are not showing at all. 
Did I do something wrong defining them? 
I am a newbie and very confused...please help!

```
#mainpage {
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white; 
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white; 

}

#mainpage a:hover{
    color: yellow; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white; 
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px yellow; 
}

#mainpage a:active {
    color: yellow; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white; 
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px yellow; 
}

#mainpage a:visited {
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white; 
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;  
}
```

Comment: It's at times like *this* that HTML is useful. I appreciate that you showed us the CSS (and kudos for that!), but describing your HTML at us is not as useful as *showing* the HTML.

Comment: #mainpage a {} means an a tag inside the #mainpage element, and not the element #mainpage. If your html would look like <div id="mainpage"><a>some text</a></div> then the above css would work for the text inside the a tag

Comment: David: Will do the next time. Thanks!

Comment: Ribot: Ohh I see! I somehow did not know that! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `#mainpage a:hover` to `a#mainpage:hover`, and repeat to the rest (visited, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for help! It was a silly mistake: I thought it should be a#mainpage:hover rather than what I did, but it didn't work in the first place, so I switched to what I have above. HOWEVER, I was mistaken, because, as you can see from the code I posted, I defined color twice for hover and active and the second one overrode the first one, showing the wrong color.

Comment: I understand. You had the solution, but it slipped by. Always try to use different colors when debugging, so that things like that don't happen. Please accept the answer since it is the solution to that problem. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the new suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`#mainpage:hover` similarly for all others...

This might work...

Comment: Thanks for help! It was a silly mistake: I thought it should be a#mainpage:hover rather than what I did, but it didn't work in the first place, so I switched to what I have above. HOWEVER, I was mistaken, because, as you can see from the code I posted, I defined color twice for hover and active and the second one overrode the first one, showing the wrong color.